# How to add pictures to shared contacts in google contacts?

Tags: google-workspace, google-apps-script, google-contacts

More specifically: is there a way to add a picture to *external* shared contacts in Google Apps for Enterprise, where the picture is shared amongst all members of my domain?

I know it is possible to add a picture to a *replica* of a contact (e.g. a directory contact that I copy to "my contacts"), but it will not share that picture with other members of my organization.

I'm also not concerned with contacts from my own domain.

Any solution, including using Google Apps Script would help.